# Could not able to load datatables in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

How would i know right order of including jquery . I am using links as follows:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="dist/js/app.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#dataTables-example').dataTable();
});
</script>
<script src="assets/js/admin.js"></script>
```

How would i know which order is right for including jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is by opening developer tools (F12) and then checking the console for any error. For example if you load bootstrap before jquery it will show you an error some like "jQuery is undefined"

Comment: I am using firebug for console . It is showing this error ""TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function""

Comment: this error usually happens when you load datatable before jquery.